# Show different times based on day

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to exclude different times based on dates but the times are disabled no matter what dates I pick. For example if I select the 28th Of September then 12 o'clock should be disabled. If I choose the 3rd of October then 1pm should disabled, however 12 and 1 are disabled right from the start and stay that way no matter what date I pick.

https://hacker0x01.github.io/react-datepicker

```
  const isSunday = (date) => {
    const day = getDay(date);
    return day !== 0;
  };

  let excluded = [
    {
      time: "12",
      date: "28/09/2020",
    },
    {
      time: "13",
      date: "03/10/2020",
    },
  ];


    <DatePickerField
      filterDate={isSunday}
      minTime={new Date(new Date().setHours(8, 0, 0))}
      maxTime={new Date(new Date().setHours(17, 0, 0))}
      excludeTimes={excluded.map((exclude, index) => {
        return setHours(
          setMinutes(new Date(), 0),
          parseInt(exclude.time)
        );
      })}
      timeIntervals={60}
      maxDate={addDays(new Date(), 3)}
      dateFormat="d/M/Y HH:mm"
      timeFormat="HH:mm"
      name="time-to-contact"
      label="Required Date *"
    />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are always returning `excluded` in `excludeTimes` props. You need to return the time only if the selected date is the date. Something like that should work. (By adding `const [value, setValue] = useState();` too).

```
<DatePickerField
  filterDate={isSunday}
  minTime={new Date(new Date().setHours(8, 0, 0))}
  maxTime={new Date(new Date().setHours(17, 0, 0))}
  excludeTimes={excluded.map((exclude) => {
    const excDate = new Date(exclude.date);
    if (
      value &&
      excDate.getDate() === value.getDate() &&
      excDate.getFullYear() === value.getFullYear() &&
      excDate.getMonth() === value.getMonth()
    ) {
      return new Date(new Date().setHours(exclude.time, 0, 0));
    }
    return null;
  })}
  timeIntervals={60}
  maxDate={addDays(new Date(), 3)}
  dateFormat="d/M/Y HH:mm"
  timeFormat="HH:mm"
  name="time-to-contact"
  label="Required Date *"
  onChange={(e) => {
    setValue(new Date(e));
  }}
  selected={value}
    />
```

Also your dates are not in the good format for JS, it should be:

```
  const excluded = [
    {
      time: "12",
      date: "09/28/2020"
    },
    {
      time: "13",
      date: "10/03/2020"
    }
  ];
```

Here's a link to a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-smoke-4nv1e?file=/src/App.js

To add exclude time for a specific day (let's say monday) you could use this:

```
const excluded = [
  {
    time: "12",
    day: 1
  }, 
]
```

And set the prop to this:

```
excludeTimes={excluded.map((exclude) => {
  if (value && value.getDay() === exclude.day) {
    return new Date(new Date().setHours(exclude.time, 0, 0));
  }
  return null;
})}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this, it is really very helpful. I just wanted to know if it is possible to make the times work for example, every Saturday and every Monday - Friday. I tried something like: `const excluded = [
    {
      time: "12",
      day: 6,
    },
  ];` And then: `const excDate = new Date(exclude.day);
                            if (
                              value &&
                              excDate.getDate() === value.getDay()
                            )` But that doesn't work at all.

Comment: You should use `exclude.day` directly in this case instead of creating a date. I edited my post with an example.

Comment: You are quite honestly my hero right now, no jokes. I really appreciate your help, thanks so much.